# Replacing two characters with one character in a char array

Tags: java, arrays, replace, char

How to replace two characters with one character in a char array? Let me explain a bit more. I have a char array of length `n` . In this char array i want to replace two characters with one character in a specified index `i`. In this process the array length is going to decrease by 1.
The idea which i came to my mind is, first create a new char array of length `n-1` then copy all elements from index `0` to index `i` (`i` excluding) then insert desired character at index `i` then copy elements from index `i+2` (`i` including) to the index `n-1`. But this process require two times `for` loop. Is there any better approach which can do the same in efficient manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or a more efficient way of doing this is to use a StringBuilder which is a wrapper for char[] and let it do it for you.

```
char[] chars = "Hello".toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(chars);
sb.replace(2, 4, "L");
System.out.println(sb);
```

prints

```
HeLo
```

You can look at the code for replace to see how it does it.

Comment: Can i create StringBuilder instance with a char array? I have char array in my hands.

Answer (score 4):

Copy array portions with [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) instead of iterating over its elements.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want a new array object, there's no faster way than by copying each array element once, so there's no more efficient method than this. If you use two calls to `System.arraycopy()`, you don't have to write the loops yourself.

If you don't need a new array object, you could just move the higher-numbered array elements down by one, which involves just half the number of copies -- but then you're going to need to keep track of the length some other way.

Comment: Okay...i get it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

It could use a single for loop. Just put in an IF statement indicating if iteration (i) = index you want to replace then do a different operation rather than just copy.

Written in basic:

```
For i = 0 to n - 1
       If i = x then
             arrayCopy(i) = replaceChars
       Else
             arrayCopy(i) = arraySource(i)
       End If
Next
```

Comment: checking every time an `if` condition from index `0` to index `n-1` would not be better perhaps. Instead of this, i should prefer two `for` loops (i mean `System.arraycopy`) from index `0` to index `i-1` and from index `i+1` index `n-1` respectively. This might increase the performance. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: ArrayCopy is better all around since can be done with two lines of code. Just was pointing out could be done with single loop.